# How to switch OR to AND in an if in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Now I seach for Rabobank OR ideal, I want them to both founded so I want to edit the condition.

```
if (/(Rabobank)|(ideal)/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )
```

Tried: `if (/(Rabobank)||(ideal)/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )`

And `if (/(Rabobank)&&(ideal)/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )`

Comment: Don't call me Greasemonkey

Comment: That regular expression with an alternation *is* an "OR". What *is* the problem?

Comment: @pst The title is backwards, read the first line of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expressions don't work like that.  Try:

```
if(/Rabobank/i.test(...) && /ideal/i.test(...)){ ... }
```

Take the `AND` out of the RegEx and let JS handle the logic.

Comment: This solution isnt working:
`if(/Rabobank/i.test(document.body.innerHTML) && /ideal/i.test(document.body.innerHTML)){ document.body.innerHTML }`

Comment: @RemcoSwienink You're not *doing anything* inside the `{ document.body.innerHTML }`.  Your code will have no effect.  The test will work correctly, it's up to you to fill in what happens inside the brackets!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `indexOf`:

```
var text = document.body.textContent.toLowerCase();

if ((text.indexOf('rabobank') !== -1) && (text.indexOf('ideal') !== -1)) {
    ...
}
```

If you *absolutely* need regex, just split it up into two tests, as outlined in the other answers.

Comment: This works. But I'm not sure it helps the op understand why his/her example doesn't work.  An explanation of *why* you're using `indexOf` instead of RegEx would be nice too.

Comment: @Madbreaks, sometimes `indexOf` is faster.  But I think that with copying the entire `body.textContent` to a lower-case string, that is probably not the case here.  Plus this solution has the added maintenance "gotcha" that you have to remember to lower-case the search terms (a gotcha that already bit the poster!).

Comment: @BrockAdams thanks.  *I know* why it might be preferable to use `indexOf`, my point is that for the sake of writing a good answer, including that bit of information as to why when op was using RegEx, Blender suggested an entirely different approach.  This happens a lot on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split it into two different regex:

```
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
if ( /Rabobank/i.test(html) && 
     /ideal/i.test(html) )
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Should use `document.body.textContent` in almost all cases. (Actually should use DOM techniques, but that's for another question.)